# Question on an example code of Javascript decorator from javascript.info website

Tags: javascript

I'm learning Javascript from javascript.info , and couldn't understand something in this code .

This is an example code from https://javascript.info/call-apply-decorators

```
function slow(x) {
  // there can be a heavy CPU-intensive job here
  alert(`Called with ${x}`);
  return x;
}

function cachingDecorator(func) {
  let cache = new Map();

  return function(x) {
    if (cache.has(x)) {    // if there's such key in cache
      return cache.get(x); // read the result from it
    }

    let result = func(x);  // otherwise call func

    cache.set(x, result);  // and cache (remember) the result
    return result;
  };
}

slow = cachingDecorator(slow);

alert( slow(1) ); // slow(1) is cached
alert( "Again: " + slow(1) ); // the same
```

I do not understand how does cachingDecorator function know what is "x" when it return function at "return function(x)". So if slow(1) is called, it magically knows x is supposed to be 1... how?

Tried to look it up, but couldn't find answer for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's just like any other function. You define a parameter `x`, and when invoking that function with `1` as its argument, the `x` parameter gets the argument. Makes no difference where or how that function was defined.

Comment: ...to be clear, `cachingDirecctor` doesn't know anything about `x`. All it does is create a `Map`, and *return* a new, separate function. I think maybe you're getting confused by the reuse of the `slow` variable.

Comment: Hi, I probably couldn't make myself clear why I'm confused. so ``cachingDecorator`` function is getting argument of function - and ``x`` seems to be an arbitrary variable that I define in ``cachingDecorator``. Then how does ``cachingDecorator`` know the argument passed in ``slow`` function and correctly match it with variable x?

Comment: oh this was really silly question. I got it suddenly.. -_- thanks for help.

Comment: It's not an arbitrary variable. It's the parameter defined for the function that's being returend.

Comment: Passing around functions is confusing at first, until it clicks and you realize how simple it actually is.

Comment: `cachingDecorator` is programmed to deal with a function `func` having one cachable argument (`x`). The new, returned function then checks this argument against the `cache` map that has been defined in a scope around it. Each time the generated function is called it will either just get an existing value or calculate it new and store it there.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point is that `cachingDecorator(func)` will return a new function on the basis of `func` that has been generated in a scope together with the map `cache`. Each time the new function (in our example: `slow` ) is called

- this cache is checked before, and used instead if a *value is found there*,
- *otherwise*: the underlying function `func` is called and the result is stored (=cached) in `cache` for the next call.

Comment: oh this was really silly question. I got it suddenly.. -_- thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an alternate code for simpler understanding:

```
let obj = {
     func(x){ console.log(this);
             return x*2; },
      okay: "cool",
}
obj.func(5);

function dec(fob){
  return function(x){
    return 100*fob(x);  
  }
}

let result = dec(obj.func);
result(2);
```

So if you see here, the call to result(2) is basically a call to a function returning 100*fob(2). i.e in turn this becomes 100*x*2. x =2 in this case. So, the output here should be 400.

Note: If you do not send any arguments while calling the decorator function, it will return undefined/Nan based on the main function logic.